# Proper layer/Object for updating a model with a request object

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, architecture

Using Sprint I have an endpoint with the following header:

```
@PutMapping("/{productId}")
Product updateProduct(@Valid @RequestBody ProductRequest productRequest) { ....
```

Where should I copy the fields from ProductRequest to the existing Product? In the service? Use a map class for that? Use the product factory? Somewhere else?

Answer (score 1):

By my opinion we should use Rest/Mvc controller layer for following:

1) Parameters validation

2) Mapping incoming parameters(`ProductRequest`) into service model (`Product`)

3) Call services with service model

4) Return result or error

So in your case you should map `ProductRequest` to Product and path `Product` to the service. You can find one of the classic sample in this article: [DTO Conversion](https://www.baeldung.com/entity-to-and-from-dto-for-a-java-spring-application):

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{id}", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
public void updatePost(@RequestBody PostDto postDto) {
    Post post = convertToEntity(postDto);
    postService.updatePost(post);
}
```

Also it is rule of thumb keep controller layer as thin as possible.